# Аналог функции Assembly.load из C# в Java

Tags: java, c#

В C# есть функция `Assembly.load` - запускающая сборку из массива байт. Нужен аналог в Java.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то [ClassLoader.defineClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-).